# THREAD 8: Signal SIGABRT When performing a segue

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

This happens when i am saving a video, I am also trying to segue to another view controller. I am not sure why the app crashes here

```
func finalExportCompletion(_ session: AVAssetExportSession) {
    PhotoManager().saveVideoToUserLibrary(fileUrl: session.outputURL!) { (success, error) in
        if success {
            ProgressHUD.showSuccess("Video Saved", interaction: true)
            self.finalVideo = session.outputURL!
            //FileManager.default.clearTmpDirectory()
            self.clipsCollectionView.reloadData()
        } else {
            ProgressHUD.show(error?.localizedDescription)
        }
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toPostVideoViewController", sender: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: session.outputURL!, is the culprit in my opinion. Make it optional and safely unwrap it.

Comment: SHOW THE UTILITIES PANEL in top right corner go to connections inspector and make sure you have deleted all extra connections made from or to the view!

Comment: Do not perform UI updates on a background thread.

Comment: I tried safely unwrapping it using

    if let video = session.outputURL! {

It gives me the error: initializer for conditional binding must have optional type, not 'URL'

Comment: @rmaddy What do you mean? Does that mean i should not perform a segue there?

Comment: I double checked, and all of my connections are okay.

Comment: Get rid of the `!`

Comment: @MichaelJajou It means what I said. All UI updates must be performed on the main queue but you are performing them on a background queue. See the answer by Reinier Melian below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your crash is issued to modifications in UI while your are in background thread, as said your crash log, and @rmaddy in his comment, `THREAD 8` is a background thread, your need execute all your UI actions in `Thread 1` which is the "Main Thread" you have to modify your code like this

```
func finalExportCompletion(_ session: AVAssetExportSession) {
    PhotoManager().saveVideoToUserLibrary(fileUrl: session.outputURL!) { (success, error) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async{
            if success {
                ProgressHUD.showSuccess("Video Saved", interaction: true)
                self.finalVideo = session.outputURL!
                //FileManager.default.clearTmpDirectory()
                self.clipsCollectionView.reloadData()
            } else {
                ProgressHUD.show(error?.localizedDescription)
            }
            //I don't know if you anyway want to go to "toPostVideoViewController" this you need to do it also in main thread
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toPostVideoViewController", sender: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be a lot simpler to use one `DispatchQueue.main.async` inside the `saveVideoToUserLibrary` callback closure since everything in there needs to be run on the main queue.

Comment: Thank you guys. I appreciate the help!